# MongoDB create replica set with authentication enabled

Tags: mongodb

I have a monogDB replica set running on windows , im trying to add users and authentication to them.

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "admin",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]
  }
);
exit;
```

```
mongo --port 27017 -u admin -p password --authenticationDatabase admin
```

```
use test
db.createUser(
    {
      user: "tester",
      pwd: "password",
      roles: [
         { role: "read", db: "test1" },
         { role: "read", db: "test2" },
         { role: "read", db: "test3" },
         { role: "readWrite", db: "test" }
      ]
    }
);
```

after creating the user I modify the cfg files of all three replica nodes changing to authorization: enabled. restarting the service and try to log in to servers.
I am able to enter with the user but all nodes changes the status to "OTHER", and if I change the authorization to unmarked (# - like it was) the replica set is working fine but the user I created doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

or does anyone know the actual steps to create replica set with authentication enabled?

Comment: Yes. The steps are in documentation.

Comment: Didn't find the steps for replica set + authentication sir

Answer (score 5):

Usually you do it the other way around. First enable authentication, then create the users. And typically all users are created in `admin` database only.

Anyway, regarding your problem: When you enable authentication then the nodes must also authenticate internally, i.e. when a replica set member connects to another replica set member.

See [Internal/Membership Authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-internal-authentication/)

The simple way is to use a keyfile for this.

First create the keyfile:

```
openssl rand -base64 756 > <path-to-keyfile>
```

If you don't have openSSL you can download it from [OpenSSL for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm). Then copy this keyfile to each replica set member.

Put this option to the MongoDB configuration files:

```
security:
  authorization: enabled 
  keyFile: <path-to-keyfile>
```

Restart the MongoDB service, then it should work.

See also [Deploy Replica Set With Keyfile Authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-with-keyfile-access-control/) or [Update Replica Set to Keyfile Authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-replica-set/) or [Update Replica Set to Keyfile Authentication (No Downtime)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-replica-set-without-downtime/)

Comment: Ok this works, but it's still possible to enter the instance without user&password. The replica set is working + I am able to enter the nodes with users. but im also able to enter like mongo --port 27017 or even remotly mongo --host x.x.x.x. how do i disable it?

Comment: You can always connect without a password. However, you cannot execute any command (apart from harmless commands like `db.help()`, etc.)

Comment: Yeah you're correct thanks for that! one last thing, whenever the replica set changes status from primary to secondary and I try to do simple find commands from the secondary it asks me again and again to do rs.secondaryOk(), is this normal?

Comment: You need to connect to the replicat set, instead to a single node. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/#connect-to-a-mongodb-replica-set

Comment: Oh so once my application connect through the connection string and not directly it wont cause problems? by the way, how can I generate key file in windows, this site didn't work to download from and currently I generated one from linux machine

Comment: Maybe use google "openssl windows binaries"? Some hits: https://sourceforge.net/projects/openssl/ https://www.npcglib.org/~stathis/blog/precompiled-openssl/

Comment: It does not matter if you use the connection string URI or not. It matters if you use only "localhost" (the default) or all members.

Comment: by all members you mean that I define the whole replica set nodes in the string?

Comment: Did you read the linked documentation? Do you like me to guess your connection string?

Comment: Yeah, I konw there's option for srv and one to mention all the nodes in the string. im just asking if i use the one with all nodes in the string, will it solve the problem with rs.secondaryOk?